# Span css grid to second child element

Tags: html, css

I would like to arrange the ul of my navigation according to the parent grid.

Imagine the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="navigation">
  <p id="content">Content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I know how to arrange the #navigation according to my grid like:

```
.container {
  grid-template-areas: nav nav nav nav;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr
}

#navigation {
 grid-area: nav;
}
```

But what can I do so that the #content starts at the second column?

I know that I could use a subgrid, but there must be a solution without?

Comment: I stumbled upon an article related to this issue the other day, maybe this will help you: [Faux Subgrid](https://zellwk.com/blog/faux-subgrid/).

Comment: Any reason not to use a subgrid? looks like the simplest solution since you are actually describing what you want using grid terms. Is your example accurate? I mean, all grid cells would be the same width and always 4 columns? or that's just a simplification of your real code?